# External users can't find users in the people picker in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, user, external

my external user can search for users in the people picker in SharePoint Online.
Regarding the [support of office](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/external-users-can-t-find-users-in-the-people-picker-in-sharepoint-online-b979de7a-4040-43aa-b00f-0b9ac93813da) support of office, we need to fill the hole email.
but even with the full email, the user doesnt show.

Any suggestion, ideas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe external users wont have access to your Azure AD and hence this issue (I would say security feature).

Why would you allow external users to see the list of users in your organization. (This is a security issue as it would expose all email IDs resulting in spam/phishing emails if data is not protected)

Comment: thank for your response, I wonder is there a role to add to the external user or another solution

Comment: well i tried the native "PeoplePicker" and it works